# Does unique_ptr automatically destruct when not referenced?

Tags: c++

Similar to the concept of GC in Java, when an object is not referenced anymore by something else, it gets marked for GC.

Does unique_ptr work similar to this?

If say I have a data structure (a tree) with nodes containing left/right `std::unique_ptr<BSTNode>`. Say I have a remove function `remove(std::unique_ptr<BSTNode>& root, int val)`, if I go to the parent of the `BSTNode` containing `val`, and assign nullptr to the left or right child field (which is the `std::unique_ptr<BSTNode>` containing `val`), would the smart pointer self destruct?

Or should I `reset` the smart pointer inside of the remove function as well? This question is mostly a scope issue that I am not understanding.

Comment: Java's GC's primary responsibility is not *ensuring objects are destroyed*, rather it is *simulating infinite memory*. It does this by destroying objects that you won't miss, at times of it's choosing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I go to the parent of the BSTNode containing val, and assign nullptr to the left or right child field (which is the std::unique_ptr containing val), would the smart pointer self destruct?

The smart pointer will destroy *the thing it points to*.

It will not destroy itself (which is what self-destruct means; you may have confused terminology here).

Comment: Ah I see, then would the smart pointer then just de-scope and eventually also be destroyed (with the thing it points to)? Its not clear to me how the smart pointer knows that it is not being used, thus to destroy the thing it points to if say the smart pointer was replaced with a nullptr with nothing else using it.

Comment: unique_ptr isn't reference counted (like shared_ptr is).  That's why you can't arbitrarily assign it (you must use std::move to transfer ownership).  When it goes out of scope it'll destroy whatever it was pointing to.  You can also call reset on it of course and that will have the same effect (the thing it was pointing to gets destroyed).

Comment: @Naz the instant the `unique_ptr` passes out of scope its destructor fires and frees the memory it manages. There is no eventually unless you are using a pointer to a `unique_ptr`, but that defeats the point of using a `unique_ptr` in the first place.

Comment: @Robinson `shared_ptr`s are not reference counted. The object they share ownership of is reference counted. The destructor of the shared pointer decrements the reference count, and the last one also destroys the pointee.

Answer (score 2):

The key to `unique_ptr` is understanding the lifespan of **stack** variables.

There's nothing inherent in `unique_ptr` that's different from other stack variables, just the use of its destructor to clean up the owned content. This is an idiom widely used before these pointers, referred to as RAII *Resource Acquisition Is Initialisation*.

If you have a `unique_ptr` on the stack, ie: declared inside some scope, it executes its destructor when you exit that scope and the stack variables are deleted.

If you have it inside some struct or class allocated on the heap, it executes its destructor when that container is deleted.